# grub rescue cant be done

Tags: dual-boot

I have a new laptop with Windows 8 on it. I made a new partition and installed Ubuntu on it. For some reason I deleted the Ubuntu partition. Now upon restart I have the grub rescue screen.   I've googled and googled and here's what I have tried:

the `ls` command gave me 4 options.  I tried more than 10 variations (hd0,msdos1) to (hd0,msdos10).  This results in either `no such partition` or `unknown file system` error messages.

Then I tried

`set perfix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub`

```
root=(hd0,msdos6)
```

(and did it with the numbers on ls command)
but it never works when I type

```
insmod normal
```

(or)

```
insmod (hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub/normal.mod
```

I still get the error.

I've tried many times with no success. Even booting from an Ubuntu CD doesn't get me to boot menu -  I press `shift`, `tab`, `escape` , `f12` but nothing happens  - only grub menu.

Comment: If you deleted Ubuntu then that's too bad.  I don't think you can recover from that.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out this recent question and answer regarding boot-repair:
[Windows 10 upgrade led to grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue)

If that doesn't work, you could try replacing grub with the Windows bootloader like this guy:

> None of the answers here worked for me in re-installing the Windows 7
>   bootloader.
>
> I tried starting with a recovery disk (USB, in my case), and
>   diagnosing startup problems, but no luck.
>
> Then I opened the console in recovery mode and ran
>
> `Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`
>
> `Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`
>
> and then restarted.
>
> Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392