# Upgraded to Windows 10, destroy my Linux partition, boot-repair didn't do anything

Tags: grubrescue, boot-repair, windows-10

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12026167/

I get dropped in grub rescue with the message "no such partition" and I don't know what to do. Can anyone give me a step-by-step on how to fix this?

Comment: Restore missing Logical partition with testdisk or parted rescue.  It is just not rewritten by Windows on Winows updates. It is still there and just needs to be in partition table. Backup current partitions first: `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt` and save to another drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do to fix.  Your Linux install has been, shall we say, obliterated.

You can reinstall, but you'll have to resize partitions with gParted live.