# No such partition grub rescue - after windows upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have Windows7 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop.

Windows required an update, which failed with an error.

My laptop has a restore to factory install option, which I attempted.  This has also gone wrong.  I now get "No such partition grub rescue" when I boot up.

Below is the output from a bootinfoscript (which I understand will show all you need to help me fix my problem)

Note: I have booted from a USB key.
Thank you in advance for any help/advice.

```
                   Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.05 20140113
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 511 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                       The integrity check of the ADV area failed. No errors 
                       found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux/syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       821,247       819,200  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda2             821,248    62,261,247    61,440,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          62,261,248    82,741,247    20,480,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4          82,743,294   625,141,759   542,398,466   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         609,517,568   625,141,759    15,624,192  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000 MB, 2000683008 bytes
64 heads, 47 sectors/track, 1299 cylinders, total 3907584 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          3,616     3,907,583     3,903,968   6 FAT16


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        EAC60D4BC60D1989                       ntfs       SYSTEM
/dev/sda2        CE1810AF18109893                       ntfs       WINDOWS
/dev/sda3        38EE9AC7EE9A7D36                       ntfs       Data
/dev/sdb1        30EE-D219                              vfat       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

========================= sdb1/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: ==========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 syslinux/chain.c32                 :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/gfxboot.c32               :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/vesamenu.c32              :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

./bootinfoscript: line 1646: [: 2.73495e+09: integer expression expected
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-BPZQv9Hh/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-BPZQv9Hh/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
  No volume groups found
```

Comment: Same as this except the exact sectors of missing partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080 You need testdisk or parted rescue.

Comment: Hi Oldfred,    thanks for the pointer.  I should have stated  I am relatively new to Linux.     I had in my initial search for a solution come across that page.  But, although the starting point seems to be the same - windows upgrade breaks grub - it was not clear which of the proposed solutions were relevant.   Out of your two options parted rescue looks the less scary option.   The instructions at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121  being the one I would follow.   However he specifies that I need to replace hda with one I am interested in.  But I do not know which one that is.

Comment: Do not go back to a post from 2007, it may or may not be valid anymore.  This user shows several of the testdisk screens, but them seemed to use parted rescue. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288988  If unsure, backup current partition table: `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt`

Answer (score 0):

There is a line which indicates a possible problem of the partition containing Linux:

```
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

You can try to mount it manaully and then reinstall GRUB. If `/dev/sda5` **really** is your Linux root partition (or if you had a `/boot` partition use that instead), from the live medium, open a Terminal and try the following*:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

When you reboot now you should getting Ubuntu without any issues. If you find that you cannot boot Windows because there is no boot menu, from the booted Ubuntu run in a Terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will detect Windows bootloader and add a corresponding entry to GRUB boot menu.

- If the partition fails to mount, somehow you corrupted it and you may need to reinstall Linux.

Comment: No, sda5 is the Linux swap partition.  The Linux partition has been deleted.

Comment: Hi Martin, if the Linux partition has been deleted, how do I restore it?