# How do I access the grub/ Ubuntu after installing windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

After installing windows 10 alongside windows 7 and ubuntu, I cannot access the grub boot menu. It boots directly to windows 10 giving the option to access windows 7 (which is nice)

I have tried reinstalling ubuntu by updating it with a new live CD, to no avail. I also noticed that someone else asked basically the same question as me here:
[No dual boot screen after upgrading to windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665236/no-dual-boot-screen-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)

But the question has been dismissed because it involves the windows boot and not the grub. I followed the advise given in the answer to that question, basically reinstalling the grub, to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10 upgrade lead into grub rescue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Did you leave Windows 10 fast startup on? Is Linux partition still shown if BIOS, if not then mikewhatever's link is best option? May be best to see details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Windows 10 is even more locked down than Windows 8 in terms of the boot process. You might be able to have GRUB boot by default using the `boot-repair` program. Search that with Google and it should be the first or second result (it's on the Ubuntu site).

Comment: if I do *sudo fdisk -l* it shows [/dev/sdb1 2048 103622655 103620608 49.4G 83 Linux ] so I think that *@mikewhatever*'s link won't help me. I'm busy downloading *boot-repair*, hopefully that doesn't make it impossible to access windows. Why doesn't the [markdown] work –

Answer (score 1):

This problem was completely solved by using these three commands in the terminal and then running the repair process through a UI:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```