# Windows 10 install corrupting grub

Tags: grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I know similar problems have cropped before, but nothing I've found so far has helped (in part because I can't make sense of most of it). So here we go:

Windows 10 started installing unprompted. I get Grub secure on restart with ls (HD0). (HD0,msdos1)... and so till 5 (all unrecognized systems). I tried Boot-Repair-Disk (recommended). It says it's fixed, but it isn't and I still get the same thing.

The Boot Info Summary is below (I've removed the hex dump because of the 30k character limit). Near the end it says `The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will not act on the MBR. Additional repair will be performed:  repair-filesystems`. I don't dare do anything yet, in fear of making the situation worse.

BTW, the Ubuntu partition on that particular machine is not really used, so I have no qualms about sacrificing it.

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub.
 => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System: 
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System: 
    Boot files:       

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 3.82 2009-06-09
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 279936 of /dev/sda4 for its
                       second stage. No errors found in the Boot Parameter
                       Block.
    Operating System: 
    Boot files:        /syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 ........>..sr>.......C..9...0...~.....~...f...M.f.f....f..0~....>E}.u......
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 1354416 of /dev/sdb1 for its
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory.
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System: 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   972,755,725   972,753,678   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         972,756,992   973,676,543       919,552  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda3         973,678,590 1,922,062,335   948,383,746   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,913,710,592 1,922,062,335     8,351,744  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       1,922,062,336 1,953,517,567    31,455,232  1c Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 8053 MB, 8053063680 bytes
16 heads, 60 sectors/track, 16384 cylinders, total 15728640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *             56    15,728,639    15,728,584   b W95 FAT32


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs  
/dev/sda1        5EFECDDAFECDAB1B                       ntfs       Windows
/dev/sda2        B4F013F6F013BD94                       ntfs      
/dev/sda4        12CE-6499                              vfat       RECOVERY
/dev/sda5        9854bca1-bf17-4c08-b7df-5eefc91e5247   swap      
/dev/sdb1        CCEE-8FEB                              vfat       USB DISK
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    QSS_CD
/dev/zram0       8d19b76c-b40e-4d0c-9cfd-1c3070750865   swap      
/dev/zram1       b38154f1-0717-4687-8df2-3a45d39535d1   swap      
/dev/zram2       520af6d4-2be1-4ba1-adc6-2db525aac2b5   swap      
/dev/zram3       7df6497a-dd57-44c6-af4a-4c3e33c7db80   swap      
/dev/zram4       600c36e0-e38d-4efa-ac39-714070979afe   swap      
/dev/zram5       61ead99b-f871-4628-a3ca-e3c5688eedcd   swap      
/dev/zram6       fff24e21-3bae-425b-b81b-e0c10f0c806a   swap      
/dev/zram7       622f0999-b2cd-4bb3-b2a8-82f577a606db   swap      

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  5 23:36 ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0_WD-WCAW31274353 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 23:37 ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0_WD-WCAW31274353-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 23:37 ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0_WD-WCAW31274353-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0_WD-WCAW31274353-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0_WD-WCAW31274353-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0_WD-WCAW31274353-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  5 19:34 ata-hp_DVD-ROM_TS-H353B_5R7286SB2A8684 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  5 23:36 usb-General_USB_Flash_Disk_0411020330002757-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 usb-General_USB_Flash_Disk_0411020330002757-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  5 23:36 wwn-0x50014ee2b0493026 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 23:37 wwn-0x50014ee2b0493026-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 23:37 wwn-0x50014ee2b0493026-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 wwn-0x50014ee2b0493026-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 wwn-0x50014ee2b0493026-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  5 19:34 wwn-0x50014ee2b0493026-part5 -> ../../sda5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sr0         /media/lubuntu/QSS_CD    iso9660    (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=999,gid=999,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)


============================== sda4/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
PROMPT 0
NOESCAPE 1
ALLOWOPTIONS 0
MENU TITLE Systeme de restauration
MENU BACKGROUND insertech.png
timeout 600
MENU AUTOBOOT Démmarage sur le disque dur dans # secondes
#color settings
MENU COLOR title 7;32;41 #40FF00 #00000000
MENU COLOR sel 7;32;41 #40FF00 #00000000
MENU COLOR hotsel 7;32;41 #00000000 #00000000
menu color pwdborder 30;47 #40FF00 #00000000
menu color pwdheader 31;47 #40FF00 #00000000
MENU HELPMSGROW 13
# Menus
# Restore image
LABEL restore
    MENU LABEL Restaurer votre systeme
    kernel /live-hd/vmlinuz
    append root=/dev/sda2 initrd=/live-hd/initrd.img bootfrom=/dev/hda boot=live union=aufs edd=on nolocales live-media-path=/live-hd ocs_prerun="mount -o ro /dev/sda2 /home/partimag" ocs_live_run="bash /home/partimag/oui.sh" ocs_live_keymap="NONE" ocs_live_batch="yes" ocs_lang="en_us.UTF-8" video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-32 toram=filesystem.squashfs noprompt 
    TEXT HELP
   Vous permet de restaurer Windows a son etat d'origine
    ENDTEXT
 
LABEL memtest
    MENU LABEL Test memoire
    kernel memtest86
    TEXT HELP
   Si la memoire contient une erreur, une ligne rouge apparaitera
    ENDTEXT
 
LABEL hdd
    MENU LABEL Test de disque dur
        KERNEL memdisk
        APPEND initrd=vivard.img
    TEXT HELP
   Permet de verifier si le disque contient des secteurs defectueux
    ENDTEXT
 
LABEL bootlocal
      menu label Demarrer sur le disque
    menu default
      localboot 1
    kernel chain.c32
    append hd0
 
MENU SEPARATOR
# Create image
LABEL create
    MENU PASSWD atelier
    MENU LABEL Usage interne
        kernel /live-hd/vmlinuz
        append root=/dev/sda2 initrd=/live-hd/initrd.img bootfrom=/dev/hda boot=live union=aufs edd=on nolocales live-media-path=/live-hd ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sda2 /home/partimag" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -q2 -b -j2 -z3 -i 2000 -rm-win-swap-hib -p poweroff saveparts backup sda1" ocs_live_keymap="NONE" ocs_live_batch="yes" ocs_lang="en_us.UTF-8" video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-32 toram=filesystem.squashfs noprompt 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============== sda4: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 chain.c32                          :  COM32R module (v3.xx)
 vesamenu.c32                       :  COM32R module (v3.xx)

=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Boot-Repair-Disk session" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd    /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title UNetbootin
timeout 100
 
label unetbootindefault
menu label Default
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
 
label ubnentry0
menu label ^Help
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 
 
label ubnentry1
menu label ^64bit session
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper  quiet splash --
 
label ubnentry2
menu label ^64bit session (failsafe)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper  noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp vga=normal --
 
label ubnentry3
menu label Boot-Repair-Disk session
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 menu.c32                           :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: write error: Broken pipe
File descriptor 9 (/proc/11191/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 17422: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[43703]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 17422: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2016-04-05__23h36 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa14
boot-sav version : 4ppa14
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa47~saucy
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa14
File descriptor 9 (/proc/11191/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 12722: /bin/sh
No volume groups found
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 29nov2014, trusty, Ubuntu, x86_64)
ls: cannot access /home/usr/.config: No such file or directory
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash -- BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz.efi

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Windows" UUID="5EFECDDAFECDAB1B" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="B4F013F6F013BD94" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="12CE-6499" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda5: UUID="9854bca1-bf17-4c08-b7df-5eefc91e5247" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="QSS_CD" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="USB DISK" UUID="CCEE-8FEB" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/zram0: UUID="8d19b76c-b40e-4d0c-9cfd-1c3070750865" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram1: UUID="b38154f1-0717-4687-8df2-3a45d39535d1" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram2: UUID="520af6d4-2be1-4ba1-adc6-2db525aac2b5" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram3: UUID="7df6497a-dd57-44c6-af4a-4c3e33c7db80" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram4: UUID="600c36e0-e38d-4efa-ac39-714070979afe" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram5: UUID="61ead99b-f871-4628-a3ca-e3c5688eedcd" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram6: UUID="fff24e21-3bae-425b-b81b-e0c10f0c806a" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram7: UUID="622f0999-b2cd-4bb3-b2a8-82f577a606db" TYPE="swap"


1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 0 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,    not-sepboot,    no-grubenv    nogrub,    no-docgrub,    no-update-grub,    32,    no-boot,    is-os,    not--efi--part,    part-has-no-fstab,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    haswinload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    bootmgr,    is-winboot,    nopakmgr,    nogrubinstall,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    standard,    farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,    not-sepboot,    no-grubenv    nogrub,    no-docgrub,    no-update-grub,    32,    no-boot,    no-os,    not--efi--part,    part-has-no-fstab,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot,    nopakmgr,    nogrubinstall,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    standard,    farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.
sda4    : sda,    not-sepboot,    no-grubenv    nogrub,    no-docgrub,    no-update-grub,    32,    no-boot,    no-os,    not--efi--part,    part-has-no-fstab,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot,    nopakmgr,    nogrubinstall,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    standard,    farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda4.

sda    : not-GPT,    BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     liveusb,    has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD1002FAEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  498GB   498GB   primary   ntfs            boot
2      498GB   499GB   471MB   primary   ntfs            diag
3      499GB   984GB   486GB   extended
5      980GB   984GB   4276MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
4      984GB   1000GB  16.1GB  primary   fat32           hidden, lba


Model: General USB Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8053MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      28.7kB  8053MB  8053MB  primary  fat32        boot


                                                                            Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
                                                                            Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram0: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram1: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram2: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram3: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram4: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram5: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram6: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram7: unrecognised disk label

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA WDC WD1002FAEX-0;
1:1049kB:498GB:498GB:ntfs::boot;
2:498GB:499GB:471MB:ntfs::diag;
3:499GB:984GB:486GB:::;
5:980GB:984GB:4276MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
4:984GB:1000GB:16.1GB:fat32::hidden, lba;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:8053MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:General USB Flash Disk;
1:28.7kB:8053MB:8053MB:fat32::boot;

                                                                            Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
                                                                            Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram0: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram1: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram2: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram3: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram4: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram5: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram6: unrecognised disk label

                                                                            Error: /dev/zram7: unrecognised disk label


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=lubuntu)
/dev/sr0 on /media/lubuntu/QSS_CD type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=999,gid=999,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda4 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda4 type vfat (rw)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sdb1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hidraw2 hpet input kmsg kvm log mapper mcelog mem net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sdb sdb1 sg0 sg1 sg2 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom usb vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control



=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  2.0G   36M  1.9G   2% /
udev           devtmpfs   2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      394M  1.3M  393M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat       7.5G  647M  6.9G   9% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   549M  549M     0 100% /rofs
none           tmpfs      4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs      2.0G  620K  2.0G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs      100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sr0       iso9660    7.2M  7.2M     0 100% /media/lubuntu/QSS_CD
/dev/sda1      fuseblk    464G  427G   38G  92% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk    449M  333M  117M  75% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda4      vfat        15G  6.8G  8.3G  45% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6563cd9f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   972755725   486376839    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       972756992   973676543      459776   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3       973678590  1922062335   474191873    5  Extended
/dev/sda4      1922062336  1953517567    15727616   1c  Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda5      1913710592  1922062335     4175872   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 8053 MB, 8053063680 bytes
16 heads, 60 sectors/track, 16384 cylinders, total 15728640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          56    15728639     7864292    b  W95 FAT32


No OS or WinEFI system
No OS or WinEFI system

=================== Recommended repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will not act on the MBR.
Additional repair will be performed:  repair-filesystems


Force Unmount all blkid partitions (for fsck) except / /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /opt /pas /proc /rofs /sys /tmp /usr /var

ntfsfix /dev/sda1
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda1.

ntfsfix /dev/sda2
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda2.

fsck -fyM /dev/sda4
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
```

Comment: You post the link that Boot-Repair gives. That also preserves formatting so it is readable. Delete above info and post link. But your issue is the Windows bug that has existed for years. Windows updates since maybe before Windows 7, rewrite partition table & leave out logical Linux partitions. Use parted rescue or testdisk. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080 Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
http://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition/665462