# Installed windows 10, grub problem, linux drive became unallocated

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have dual boot Linux + Windows 8. Today I've tried updating to windows 10 and after a while got error on boot:

```
error no such partition
entering rescue mode
grub rescue>
```

Listing all the drives using ls, gives "unknown filesystem" on every one. (So I cannot set prefix/boot.)

I have booted with liveUSB opened gparted and noticed that /dev/sda4 which used to be linux, became unallocated.

I have tried boot-repair, did not helped.
I have tried putting windows8 usb and choose ~"fix boot option", did not help too.

Ideas are much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
[GParted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmf7p.png)

This is how my drive looks like, somehow after windows upgrade /dev/sda4 became "extended". I know that this is where linux files are.

At very worst I just want to get my files from Linux back. I'm trying to use TestDisk, but when trying to view files in that partition it gives me "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged." Any ideas how can I recover files?

EDIT2:

Thanks for suggestion oldFred. I'm trying to use parted to restore files/partition. This is what parted print gives me:

```
Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system  Flags
 1      2048s       1026047s    1024000s    primary   ntfs         boot
 2      1026048s    488631857s  487605810s  primary   ntfs
 3      488632320s  489639935s  1007616s    primary   ntfs         diag
 4      489644030s  976771071s  487127042s  extended               lba
 5      911235072s  976771071s  65536000s   logical   ntfs
```

EDIT FINAL: I was able to find missing partition using "parted" and following oldFred posts. Thank you everyone for the help. Problem solved!

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu. Boot-repair or Windows fixes do not work, given the situation, obviously.

Comment: I really hope you have backups. If you don't, there's a chance you can recover the EXT4 partition before doing the repairs.

Comment: Wait if your windows was updated to latest version i.e. anniversary update then this happens ...if you are having really important data in ubuntu then just switch back to previous windows version u had.u will get unallocated disk back..m not sure but This is weird ! read the post on Google such as 'linux partitions deleted after windows anniversary update'.

Comment: @sardapv Are these the right instructions? [How to Roll Back Builds and Uninstall Updates on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/235474/how-to-roll-back-builds-and-uninstall-updates-on-windows-10/)

Comment: No u cant downgrade once u upgrade.. for that u need iso file of older version of windows ..these link is about how to stop automatic updates to and select manual update to install not all....using tools like minitool partition wizard in bootable format can recover data from unallocated memories..m not sure about ext4 but they might

Comment: @sardapv Read the section 'Uninstall Major Updates, or “Builds”'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows deleted your LInux partition but it still is there and just needs to be re-added to partition table. You can use testdisk or parted rescue.

Some then work, others need grub or fsck but most are able to recover missing partition. Of course you do have good backups just in case of issues?

[Windows 10 upgrade led to grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080)

Use parted rescue to restore missing partition details in post #22

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1775331
http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/rescue.html
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/faq.php/#faq-22

Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk

['Upgraded' to Windows 10 on dual boot, and can't boot to Ubuntu partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition/665462)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I have tried using parted and updated thread with the result, however I could only find swap drive.

Comment: Parted or gparted only shows swap. It is the missing partition you want and space is currently shown. So you need parted rescue or testdisk.

Comment: Parted rescue uses sectors like your parted list. Start needs to be a few sectors after the start of the extended shown as 489644030s and ends a few sectors before the start of NTFS at 911235072. If both ext4 & swap missing then testdisk may work better.

Comment: Thank you oldFred! I've done it and parted managed to found my ext4 partition, I was able to restore it, linux drive appeared and everything started working! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem once before and don't worry this solution below will get rid of your problems away for sure.

1. Download and install spotmau boot suit 2012 to another computer
2. Get at least 4 GB USB Drive
3. Run spotmau boot suit and make your USB Drive Bootable by its ISO file.
4. Plug the USB to your laptop and press F12 to boot from USB liveboot
5. You will see temporary environment of windows. Open Boot suit icon on Desktop and click on startup recovery at the left side tab
6. Scan for boot mgr and copy bootmgr or try replace it.
7. Restart the computer, and should work

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem once before and don't worry this solution below will get rid of your problems away for sure.

1- Download and install spotmau boot suit 2012 to another computer
2- get at least 4 GB USB Drive
3- run spotmau boot suit and make your USB Drive Bootable by its ISO file.
3. Plug the USB to your laptop and press F12 to boot from USB liveboot
4. You will see temporary environment of windows. Open Boot suit icon on Desktop and click on startup recovery at the left side tab
5. Scan for boot mgr and copy bootmgr or try replace it.
6. Restart the computer, and should work

Good luck.

You can't see your partition because it converted to GPT. The easiest thing to do is, on your temporary environment click start and type 'diskmgmt.msc'. The you should see your hard disk labeled as gpt or ext4. Format that labeled partition to NTFS file type and do the former steps 3 to 5 again. 
hope it'll work.