# Windows 10 Creators breaks Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

Disclaimer: I know very little about Grub. I also know there are plenty of similar questions to mine that I've looked over, but last time this happened I tried a few solutions and ended up breaking my Windows partition (which is all I have right now) so I'd like to get some advice.

---

I was hesitating about installing the Windows 10 Creators update after I had problems with the Anniversary Update. I'm not sure if it's just bad luck, but it led to me reinstalling Ubuntu last time. I'd prefer not to have to do that again.

I know it's not much but I did ask the Windows Dev team on Twitter before upgrading and they said [everything would be fine](https://twitter.com/windowsdev/status/890288752643461121).

After upgrading I got this screen on booting:

[image: First Grub screen]

I did some googling and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/655279/176285) seemed to be an answer with plenty of upvotes so I tried

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

However on the next reboot I got the same screen. When I tried `exit` I got another Grub screen but with an error:

[image: Second Grub error]

After doing `exit` twice on this screen it started booting into Windows.

A lot of people mention boot repair so I tried that next by booting into a USB version of Ubuntu 16.04 I had and running it from there. It did it's thing and produced [this report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25602514/). After rebooting there was no change and got the same screens I mentioned above.

I also just had a look at GParted and saw that sda7 (which I think it my Ubuntu partition) had a filesystem type of unknown. I don't have the output now, but I think when I did `sudo fdisk -l` it actually showed it as an Ubuntu partition, or not "unknown" at least.

My question is can I get my Ubuntu partition back?

Update: I've tried running TestDisk and after a deep scan get this result:

[image: testdisk result]

I tried to list the files on the the partitions with the largest sectors, one of them shows a Windows filesystem, the other says "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged."

Comment: Please see my answer for this same problem at https://askubuntu.com/questions/957117/windows-10-major-update-wiped-grub-how-do-i-recover-partitions-properly/957142#957142.

Comment: Please remember to vote for it if it is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the answer with the results of testdisk. I'm not sure what to do with them.

Comment: What does it look like before the deep scan?