# Stuck on grub rescue after windows update attempted

Tags: grub2, system

I had a dual boot system with ubuntu and win10 but tonight windows attempted an update which has messed it up and left me in grub rescue.

I am complete novice in Linux and I cant boot from usb otherwise would just reinstall

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/961387/grub-fails-to-boot-after-windows-upgrade/961419#961419

Answer (score 0):

You have to put an Ubuntu ISO onto a USB stick and boot from that. After loading the live version of Ubuntu you'll have to `chroot` into your system and `update-grup`. Grub will find all your partitions, both Windows and Linux, and you'll be able to choose at boot time again.

Checkout this [Ubuntu Help Page for Grub Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Recover_Grub_2).