# Laptop opens up into emergency boot mode, partion does not start at physical sector boundary

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-partition

My laptop suddenly one day stopped working. (I wasn't able to write anything onto the disk). When I restarted it, it booted up into a emergency boot mode. After I ran fdisk -l, it says, Partition 3 (one containing the os), does not start at physical sector boundary.

```
Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048     206847     204800   100M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2          206848  209717247  209510400  99.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       209719294  629147647  419428354   200G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4       629147648 1953521663 1324374016 631.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       209719296  307373592   97654297  46.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       625242112  629147647    3905536   1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       307376128  625233919  317857792 151.6G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

How can I fix this?

Here is the complete [fdisk -l result](https://pastebin.com/0jBuvDvD)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You've provided us with stats and details about your partitioning, but little about what is 'normal'.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?  What other OS are you using?  What change was last done (were you using windows & it updated?  or ... ??)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/961387/grub-fails-to-boot-after-windows-upgrade/961419  (Grub fails to boot after windows upgrade)