# "Unable to install grub2" while installing Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu

I recently got a Lenovo Ideapad and I want to dual boot it with Lubuntu for studying purpose,and probably for daily uses. Its built-in OS is Windows 10 and it has a 1TB hard drive.

I've made a separate 50GB partition just for Lubuntu and a live USB to install it.

It seems fine until I got an error message said that the installer cannot install grub2 on the selected hard drive

I know some people asked the exact same question before but I am not sure if that is applicable for my case

Comment: And who are these people?

Comment: If you are running Lubuntu just for study purposes, you may be better served using a virtual machine:  Some of the Windows updates have been causing problems for Linux disk partitions in dual boot systems.

Comment: @Charles Green I forget to mention that I would also use it as my daily driver

Comment: @sosad9556 Good luck with the interoperability issues!  The problem with Windows updates is outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition/665462), and the advantage to using a VM is that you can have both OSs running at the same time.

Comment: You probably also want to read through [https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Check your booting mode preferences. Your Lenovo might be preferring legacy over UEFI, and the install media has both, so a legacy install fails because there is no place to put grub (no bios_grub flagged partition) on a GPT disk.