# How to get a partition back after choosing erase disk and install, but stopping the process there

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

My laptop is a Dell 7567 with no SSD, Windows 10, SSHD 1tb

I have created a volume to install Ubuntu 16.04.5 (30gb). But I made a mistake when choosing to erase the disk. I went back immediately, so please notice that no installing process ran.

However, the list of partitions of my laptop has changed, and Windows lost its partitions. So I can't run Ubuntu or Windows, Using *Try Ubuntu* right now.

Originally, there was a C drive for Windows, D drive for data and 30gb unallocated for Ubuntu.

I know when the option **Erases the disk and install Ubuntu** is checked, it will collect all the partitions of hard disk. But I stopped before the install process. Is there any way to get the partitions back for Windows, because I need the data? I hope it was not wiped.
[now the partitions looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfUqI.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, the partitions have been erased. I don't know of a way for a regular user to recover data fron a deleted partition, you could try a specialized service.

Comment: First try testdisk and/or parted rescue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition