# Grub ends in bash after resizing Windows partition from inside Windows on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-10

I resized Windows partition with Aoemi Partition which obviously messed up boot. I am running Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot and the PC shows Grub bash on boot. From Bios i can boot to Windows. How can I repair this?
Edit: From LiveCD Ubuntu GParted i see the Windows partition but the Ubuntu shows as unallocated

Edit 2: Output from boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8P33WYN2pN/

Comment: You are not showing any ext4 partitions? It only used to be an issue with Windows rewriting MBR partitions. It does look like you have unallocated space between nvme0n1p3 & p4. See what parted recovery or testdisk show. https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition

Comment: Prior to the problem i shrinked windows partition nvme0n1p3 by 20 GB, where i should point the "Start?" in parted then?

Comment: If you know the approx. sector it would be where the NTFS ended before the shrink.

Comment: Ok, I got the partition ranges and partition table from testdisk, then i ran boot-repair and got grub back. Successfully booted to Ubuntu. But now i can not access windows, boot ends with 0xc000000e (no boot file). I don't want tu run windows repair tool, as i expect it would mess things up again. Is there a way? Thanks.

Comment: It was the resize of NTFS that caused issue. You probably need to run chkdsk as after any resize, NTFS needs chkdsk. It keeps in partition boot sector size of partition which must match partition table, & chkdsk will update the partition boot sector. I would back up partition table just to have a copy. Backup partition table structure to text file & save to external device.
`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt`