# How to fix grub in dual-boot windowa10 and ubuntu? I don't see where Ubuntu is installed!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop alongside with Windows 10 and it was working well with grub to choose which OS I want to boot into UNTIL windows did update and I got grub rescue error when turning on my laptop. I googled it and used Boot-Repair (the recommended repair) to fix it and when restart, it boot directly to windows without grub and I no more able to access Ubuntu. I tried several solutions but nothing fixed the problem. I tried again with Boot-Repair and got this output http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QVV7FRPmFB/ In Ubuntu live-USB when trying to install Ubuntu I don't get reinstall I got only install and I see the following partitions.

[image: partitions]

```
Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (4.04-4.07) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 8216 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2           1,026,048   790,830,638   789,804,591   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         790,831,102   975,728,639   184,897,538   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         943,175,680   975,728,639    32,552,960  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 2055 MB, 2055208960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 249 cylinders, total 4014080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048     4,014,079     4,012,032   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        E85857DC5857A858                       ntfs       System-reserviert
/dev/sda2        9AB85DEBB85DC683                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        107f953b-3e7b-4b18-8da1-979a384b2575   swap       
/dev/sdb1        9275-8FF3                              vfat       UBUNTU 14_0

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 20 10:43 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_M.2_500GB_S33DNX0J204997B -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20 10:43 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_M.2_500GB_S33DNX0J204997B-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20 10:43 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_M.2_500GB_S33DNX0J204997B-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20  2019 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_M.2_500GB_S33DNX0J204997B-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20  2019 ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_M.2_500GB_S33DNX0J204997B-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 20 10:35 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_395E877E-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20  2019 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_395E877E-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 20 10:43 wwn-0x5002538d41bade2a -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20 10:43 wwn-0x5002538d41bade2a-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20 10:43 wwn-0x5002538d41bade2a-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20  2019 wwn-0x5002538d41bade2a-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 20  2019 wwn-0x5002538d41bade2a-part5 -> ../../sda5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 9 (/proc/9018/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 15425: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[55226]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 15425: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20190320_1035 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa65
boot-sav version : 4ppa65
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa65
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS, trusty, Ubuntu, i686)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash --- maybe-ubiquity
ls: cannot access /home/usr/.config: No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Windows 10 (loader):Windows:chain

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System-reserviert" UUID="E85857DC5857A858" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="9AB85DEBB85DC683" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="107f953b-3e7b-4b18-8da1-979a384b2575" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 14_0" UUID="9275-8FF3" TYPE="vfat"


1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 0 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not EFI-compatible.
EFI in dmesg.
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000008FF83000 000042 (v01 LENOVO TP-R0F   00001100 PTEC 00000002)
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000008FF4A000 00013E (v01 LENOVO TP-R0F   00001100 PTEC 00000002)
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    notbiosboot, /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    notbiosboot, /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Samsung SSD 850;
1:1049kB:525MB:524MB:ntfs::boot;
2:525MB:405GB:404GB:ntfs::;
3:405GB:500GB:94.7GB:::;
5:483GB:500GB:16.7GB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:2055MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk;
1:1049kB:2055MB:2054MB:fat32::boot, lba;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL
sda   disk          465.8G
sda1  part ntfs       500M System-reserviert
sda2  part ntfs     376.6G
sda3  part              1K
sda5  part swap      15.5G
sdb   disk            1.9G
sdb1  part vfat       1.9G UBUNTU 14_0
loop0 loop squashfs   1.1G

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sda      0  0  0 running
sda1     0  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2     0  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda3     0  0  0
sda5     0  0  0         [SWAP]
sdb      1  0  1 running
sdb1     1  0  1         /cdrom
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlay (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sdb1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri drm_dp_aux0 drm_dp_aux1 drm_dp_aux2 drm_dp_aux3 ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hidraw2 hpet hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-2 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 input kmsg kvm lightnvm log mapper mcelog media0 mei0 mem memory_bandwidth net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx ptp0 pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda5 sdb sdb1 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd stderr stdin stdout tpm0 uhid uinput urandom userio v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/sda1
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 08 00 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  f8 9f 0f 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  aa a6 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  58 a8 57 58 dc 57 58 e8  |........X.WX.WX.|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/sda2
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 a8 0f 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  2e 76 13 2f 00 00 00 00  |.........v./....|
00000030  00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  83 c6 5d b8 eb 5d b8 9a  |..........]..]..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 44 61 74 65  |............Date|
00000190  6e 74 72 84 67 65 72 2d  4c 65 73 65 66 65 68 6c  |ntr.ger-Lesefehl|
000001a0  65 72 00 0d 0a 42 4f 4f  54 4d 47 52 20 6b 6f 6d  |er...BOOTMGR kom|
000001b0  70 72 69 6d 69 65 72 74  00 0d 0a 4e 65 75 73 74  |primiert...Neust|
000001c0  61 72 74 20 6d 69 74 20  53 74 72 67 2b 41 6c 74  |art mit Strg+Alt|
000001d0  2b 45 6e 74 66 0d 0a 00  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |+Entf...estart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a3 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.7G   12K  7.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  1.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat      2.0G  1.1G  840M  58% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   7.7G  159M  7.6G   3% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G   28K  7.7G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     7.7G   52M  7.7G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      fuseblk   500M  326M  175M  66% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk   377G  354G   23G  94% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x846fd5c6

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048   790830638   394902295+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       790831102   975728639    92448769    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       943175680   975728639    16276480   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2055 MB, 2055208960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 249 cylinders, total 4014080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003e5fc

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     4014079     2006016    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)



=================== Recommended repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will restore the [(generic mbr)] MBR in sda, and make it boot on sda1.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


Will restore the MBR_TO_RESTORE : sda (generic mbr) into sda
dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
0+1 records in
0+1 records out

Boot successfully repaired.
```

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up is off, Windows will turn that back on. And Windows in BIOS/MBR boot mode often "forgets" to include Linux partition back into partition table. Data/partition is there, just not in partition table. You can use testdisk or parted rescue. Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288988 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 10 Anniversary Update**, and the more recent **Windows 10 Creators Update**, have a really bad habit of wiping out Linux partitions on **MBR disks**. Microsoft has known about this bug for quite some time, but has chosen not to fix it. Sounds like you're a victim.

Recovery is possible, but it can be tricky.

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Open `Software & Updates` and make sure that all of your software repositories (except proposed) are enabled.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update           # update the software database
sudo apt-get install testdisk # install testdisk
man testdisk                  # read the manual
sudo testdisk                 # start testdisk
```

You can also get specific instructions here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Help for photorec here: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

**Note**: after recovery, strongly consider changing your MBR formatted disk to GPT format, so future MS updates won't wipe it again.