# Boot-repair unable to repair both windows boot and ubuntu 20.04.2 login in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, login, boot-repair

Here is my (horrible!) computer situation after one day taking terrible decisions:

- I had a dual boot windows / ubuntu and my ubuntu partition was running out of space.
- I wanted to shrink my windows 10 partition with AOMEI partition assistant (really bad reflex I will figure out...) to make space for ubuntu and ended up in the same situation as [Ubuntu partition showing "unallocated space" after shrinking windows 10 partition with AOMEI partition assistant](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163906/ubuntu-partition-showing-unallocated-space-after-shrinking-windows-10-partitio).
- So I tried to use `testdisk` as described in https://www.tecmint.com/install-testdisk-data-recovery-tool-in-linux/ from a life USB with an 20.04.2 ubuntu version. It did allow me to recover the ubuntu boot but after a long time loading to reach the login screen, I'm unable to log in...
- I tried using `boot-repair` a first time (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but it didn't solve the problem: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TJDKtQZxdy/
- Then I desperately tried to use `parted`, but did not manage to recover ubuntu session access.
- I finally tried again to use `boot-repair` desactivating first the secure boot option, but once again it terminated successfully without solving the login problem. Here is its outputted summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rGPnZT3CmM/
- In my desperate process, I broke my boot to the windows partition too...

And here I am asking for any help, by any chance if there still is hope to recover access to my Ubuntu and Windows I would be infinitely thankful.

EDIT 1: [Screen when booting on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzl6E.jpg)

EDIT 2: I've been able to recover access to my Ubuntu session thanks to `testdisk` and this [Step By Step tutorial](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). When I boot windows, I still bump into the screen from EDIT 1 though. I'll close this question if one suggests it is not the appropriate place to answer.

Comment: Boot-Repair is Linux repairs, not Windows. It shows it reinstalled grub without error & that also added Windows to grub menu. But grub will not boot Windows that is hibernated nor needs chkdsk & after a resize it needs chkdsk. Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI and maybe f8 into repair console to run chkdsk?

Comment: I added to my question a photo of the screen when booting Windows from UEFI. I do not manage to access the repair console up to now, I am trying but not sure it is doable without any USB or CD in my situation. Thank you @oldfred.