# Windows deleted linux partition .. now on grub rescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I had dual boot - Windows and linux. Due to windows upgrade I had to make windows boot partition as active (by using windows disk management).

After windows update when I made grub boot partition as active, I am getting grub rescue> prompt on reboot.

Looks like windows disk management has deleted some unix partitions, but I am not sure). Please let me know how to boot now in windows or linux?

FYI, ls gives:
(hd0), (hd0,msdos5), (hd0,msdos3), (hd0,msdos2), (hd0,msdos1)
Out of which ls gives  (hd0,msdos3) as ext3 .  and all other partitions as unknown.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  But Windows is known to "forget" to correctly rewrite partition table on updates & leave off Linux partitions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition

Comment: Thanks.. Looks like /boot partition is available, but main / partition is deleted by windows disk partitioner . To my surprise it also deleted its own one of windows partition :(

Comment: Is there any way, I can make the Free space shown in disk partition , marked as ext again? I believe only partition table might have been corrupted not the data

Comment: See link above, it has a user who tried testdisk & parted rescue. If you know approximate start & end sectors, parted rescue may be easier. And if one partition is missing.

Comment: testdisk is very good.. it is not only showing lost partition, but is also copying files from unix to windows. Awesome..

Comment: Please note that this happened to me today and the disk deleted was different from Windows C: drive. The circumstances were that I had left in a USB hard drive which hadn't been uncleanly mounted. When I rebooted to linux, i got this error. Do you think it's because Windows detected an error on the USB drive and so went nuts fixing errors on other non-C: drives?