# I broke my Ubuntu partition in a dual-system after resizing from Windows to give more space to Linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I hope I can get some help here.

I start using a dual-system boot with Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10 Home and am loving Linux. It feels much great and faster.

Nevertheless, sometimes I used Windows for specific software I could't find an easy equivalent on Linux (ex.: Graph Pad Prism). While in one of those Windows pre-historical adventures, I had an 'confusing idea' to give more space to the beloved Ubuntu partition. I think that was a premature mistake in getting basic instructions first.

I use the same software (AOMEI Partition Assistant SE) I used before to take out 150GB+- space from C: OS Windows partition and allow Ubuntu installation. I thought it was a good idea to give 250Gb+- more and  tried to to reduce the size of the C: OS partition to increase the unallocated partition where I installed Ubuntu.

Nevertheless, after the second attempt on the software it showed a complete message and when I boot the machine I get the message saying bash like "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, Tab lists possible ......". SO the mess was already done.

Could you guys give me any help in how to undo this? Or if there is any way to correct it? I have search in several foruns that gave some clue of what mess I done but I am not sure how to correct it yet.

I am using the AOMEI software from Windows to check for bad sectors in the now 400GB+- unallocated partition where Ubunutu was previously running and it has already found 51 bad sectors. It will take some hours to scan everything and I am really not sure this will help in any way.

When I type exit in the grub interface I can see another interface that shows the boots to Windows and now what seems like two Ubuntu boots with the same name one before and one after the Windows one. I cannot run Linux and had to used the Windows, but it feels heellish now. Can anyone help? I stil have one flashdrive with the original Ubuntu 19.04 installation I used before from which I can run an image of Ubuntu without installing it.

I will have to reformat my attempt to give size to the Ubuntu OS partition? Will I loose the files and installations? Can anyone help me throught this? Maybe I can use the gparted software? But how to run it from Linux now it both boots are unnacessible?

Thank you all in advance!!
Golden Laroc

EDIT: I have booted from a flash drive but could not see or save the files on Ubuntu. I can only see an unformatted partition on both windows and linux. I also tried to run testdisk from flash boot but could not without root access. On windows I can't perform a full scan without the laptop freezing.

I have this question now: I dont care about the files, but can I solve this by formating the now unformatted partition and reinstalling Linux? Can I fromat it with WIndows and then install Ubuntu with the flash drive again? Would the broken partition table on boot be repaired with this only?

EDIT 2: I have backup most of the files and am missing using Linux. I believe the partition is a GTP partition but I run EaseUS on windows and it showed the Linux partition but with BAD chances to recover it. If reinstalling (or formatting/resintalling) Linux fix this GRUB broken loader partition on boot I would happily do it.

EDIT 3: It worked again when I reinstall Ubunutu from the flash drive. I have lost some files and some software configuration but nothing irreparable. Thanks for the suppport.

Comment: Boot with the flash drive and see if it will read your ubuntu partition and see if you can read files.  If you can, then you can copy/move files to a safe hard drive and just reinstall on new size.  I would be looking for a new hard drive soon.

Comment: There have been several recent posts where users of AOMEI tool have not re-written the Linux partition back into partition table. Post this in question above to preserve formatting: `sudo parted -l /dev/sd[a-z]` If NVMe drive post that also.  If partition is missing you may be able to use parted rescue or testdisk to restore missing partition. I can then post links as I have saved several.

Comment: I would boot into a rescue disk and have a look at the drive from Linux. If you created a  GPT partition there should be a backup partition on the disk that you can restore to using `parted`. After you get your partition table back and the drive working again you can run $> `resize2fs /dev/sdXX` and $> `e2fsck /dev/sdXX`.

Comment: I have booted from a flash drive but could not see or save the files on Ubuntu. I can only see an unformatted partition on both windows and linux. I also tried to run testdisk from flash boot but could not without root access. On windows I can't perform a full scan without the laptop freezing. i have a question, can I solve this by formating the now unformatted partition and reinstalling Linux? Would the broken partition table on boot be repaired with this only?

Comment: If you reinstall it, you totally erase everything. Do you have good backups? Only if it sees an existing install may it offer to save some data. Testdisk or parted rescue have worked for others. Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition You need some idea of start & end sectors. If only partition missing, then end of previous & start of next or end of drive should work.

Comment: Yes. I have backup most of the files and am missing using Linux. I believe the partition is a GTP partition but I run EaseUS on windows and it showed the Linux partition but with BAD chances to recover it. If reinstalling (or formatting/resintalling) Linux fix this GRUB broken loader partition on boot I would happily do it.

Comment: It worked again when I reinstall Ubunutu from the flash drive. I have lost some files and some software configuration but nothing irreparable. Thanks for the suppport, specially oldfred.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please consider writing your own answer to the question so that others can learn from your experience. Put your answer in the space labeled **Your Answer**.