# Boot-Repair failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-repair

I have got four partitions on my Ubuntu 18.04. My var partition somehow got filled up, and I used a live USB using the GParted utility to increase the size of the partition. That went well, but now Ubuntu will not boot to the login screen.

I get this error:

```
ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access width. Defaulting to byte size
```

Upon going to journal I get more errors, see attached.

I then ran Boot-Repair, but that failed. Luckily it gave me the URL below with the log files. I have emailed them to the utility owner, and I haven't got a reply yet.

[Boot-Repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cKK6FnMVgd/)

Partial results of Boot-Repair:

```
chroot  update-grub
chroot: cannot change root directory to 'update-grub': No such file or directory
umount: /sys: target is busy.
umount: /dev/pts: target is busy.
umount: /dev: target is busy.

An error occurred during the repair.
```

Comment: Boot-Repair does not work with /var as separate partition. You have to use chroot & include that partition. Usually for desktops best not to have /boot & /var as separate partitions as just more partitions to manage size of. And you now do not have sda5 which was swap. But swap is now sda4 which was /var. The fstab entry for mount of /var shows UUID that does not exist. It looks like you deleted partition, and did not resize it.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this, that is true I deleted the old partition in order to increase the bar. Is there a way to salvage this without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: You show space, was that where /var was? If so testdisk or parted rescue should be able to recover it. Testdisk finds all the old versions of partitions, so you have to select correct combination. Parted rescue requires you to specify start & end which will be end of previous partition and start of next after unallocated. Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition  backup partition table before any changes just in case.
`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt`

Comment: Excellent thanks. I will try and report back.