# Deleted Windows 10 MBR Trying to Fix Ubuntu Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, boot-repair, mbr

I have a dual-boot Win10/Ubuntu 16 system.  After Windows updated itself one time, I lost the ability to boot into Ubuntu.  Trying to fix that with boot-repair, I mistakenly deleted the Windows 10 MBR (and my Windows Recovery CD is corrupted).  Any way to restore that?  I have a [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bxpdbnqysG/) here.

Comment: Ubuntu 16?  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 16? which is a very different system to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*desktop or server*). Ubuntu has both *yy* releases and *yy.mm* releases, and they are different products.

Comment: Move boot flag from sdb2 as it does not have all the Windows boot files to sdb1 and select sdb as Windows boot drive. Turn off Windows fast start up.  Reboot Live Installer in BIOS mode, since you have BIOS installs, but it is not showing any Linux files for booting in your Linux partition sdc1. Windows in BIOS mode is known to delete Linux partitions. Did you have a install in sdb? Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition May be better to install grub in sdc, to boot install in sdb.

Comment: @oldfred - Thanks so much for your info, but I have no idea how to do what you're saying.  Can you spell it out step-by-step for me?

Comment: @guiverc - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Do not know Windows commands for moving boot. Actual command is set active, but you have to mount partitions with Windows, I think. With gparted just right click on sdb2 and remove boot flag & right click on sdb1 and add boot flag.

Comment: @oldfred  Moving boot flags worked.  Thanks so much!  I can boot back into Windows. Dual-boot will have to wait a bit longer.