# Errors while installing Ubuntu 20.04 on a Mac Mini A1993

Tags: 20.04, boot-repair, grub-efi, gpt, mac-mini

Idecided to install Ubuntu on my Mac Mini, and delete the macOS partition. While installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my Mac Mini 2018 model A1993 I came across some errors and the installer wasn't able to finish. The first fatal error was `grub-install '/dev/nvme0n1' failed`. Then I ran Boot-Repair and it showed that `Locked NVRAm is detected`. Also the paste URL was indicating that `Both primary and backup GPT are corrupted. Try making a fresh table and using Parted's rescue to recover partitions`. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? This is my first time doing this type of install.

Error 1:

[image: Error 1]

Error 2:

[image: Error 2]

GParted partitions:

[image: GParted partitions]

Boot-Repair error:

[image: Boot-Repair error]

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vm6gZhNyJJ/

```
============================ Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.
cat: /sys/firmware/efi/vars/SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/data: Input/output error

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:        nvme0n1p1/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in nvme0n1p2/fstab
Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi
No nvme0n1p2/boot/efi/efi/ ubuntu/mint folder
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 apt-get -y update
Purge the GRUB of nvme0n1p2
grub-efi-amd64-signed available
The following additional packages will be installed:
efibootmgr grub-efi-amd64-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
efibootmgr grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-efi-amd64-signed
DEBCHECK debOK
shim-signed available
Please type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" dpkg --configure -ansudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" apt-get install -fynsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub*-common shim-signed
shim-signed available
linux-headers-generic available
linux-signed-generic NOT available (apt-cache policy  problem)
Then type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-headers-generic

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub

== Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-headers-generic of nvme0n1p2 ==

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.13

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
show_order(): Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0080": Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "BootFFFF": Input/output error

uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: Cannot read EFI Boot* variables.
grub-install: warning: read_file: could not read from file: Input/output error.
grub-install: warning: vars_get_variable: read_file(/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0080-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var) failed: Input/output error.
grub-install: warning: efi_get_variable: ops->get_variable failed: Input/output error.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Input/output error.
Exit code: 1

dosfsck -a /dev/nvme0n1p1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Automatically removing dirty bit.
Free cluster summary wrong (123043 vs. really 121706)
Auto-correcting.
Performing changes.
/dev/nvme0n1p1: 25 files, 9078/130784 clusters

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: Cannot read EFI Boot* variables.
grub-install: warning: read_file: could not read from file: Input/output error.
grub-install: warning: vars_get_variable: read_file(/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0080-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var) failed: Input/output error.
grub-install: warning: efi_get_variable: ops->get_variable failed: Input/output error.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Input/output error.
Exit code: 1

rm -Rf /dev/nvme0n1p1/ubuntu .. fedora

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: Cannot read EFI Boot* variables.
grub-install: warning: read_file: could not read from file: Input/output error.
grub-install: warning: vars_get_variable: read_file(/sys/firmware/efi/vars/Boot0080-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var) failed: Input/output error.
grub-install: warning: efi_get_variable: ops->get_variable failed: Input/output error.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Input/output error.
Exit code: 1

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
show_order(): Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0080": Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "BootFFFF": Input/output error
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr).

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.

Locked-NVram detected.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, nvme0n1p1 
                       starts at sector 2048. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, nvme0n1p1 starts at sector 1. According to the 
                       info in the boot sector, nvme0n1p1 has 131072 
                       sectors.. But according to the info from the partition 
                       table, it has 16414 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on nvme0n1p2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
This session has been detected as 'live' because df -Th / contains overlay



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 113 GiB, 121332826112 bytes, 29622272 sectors
Disk identifier: 3A71B754-BCE5-474C-B9AD-997AFC849E3F
           Start      End  Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    256   131327   131072   512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 131328 29622050 29490723 112.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 14.66 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x2cf4ba3a
      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *          0  5999871  5999872  2.9G  0 Empty
sda2       5271500  5279499     8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda3       6000640 30719999 24719360 11.8G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.7GB:scsi:512:512:unknown: USB DISK 2.0:;
nvme0n1:121GB:nvme:4096:4096:gpt:APPLE SSD AP0128M:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:121GB:121GB:ext4::;

Free space (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:115712MiB:nvme:4096:4096:gpt:APPLE SSD AP0128M:;
1:0.02MiB:1.00MiB:0.98MiB:free;
1:115711MiB:115712MiB:0.84MiB:free;
sda:15000MiB:scsi:512:512:unknown: USB DISK 2.0:;

gdisk (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

MBR: hybrid
GPT: present
Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 29622272 sectors, 113.0 GiB
Disk identifier (GUID): 3A71B754-BCE5-474C-B9AD-997AFC849E3F
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 29622266
Partitions will be aligned on 256-sector boundaries
Total free space is 466 sectors (1.8 MiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1             256          131327   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
2          131328        29622050   112.5 GiB   8300
MBR: MBR only
Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sda: 30720000 sectors, 14.6 GiB
Disk identifier (GUID): 972F6C9F-26F2-465E-ADD9-849F4A1D2AE2
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 30719966
Partitions will be aligned on 4-sector boundaries
Total free space is 5992606 sectors (2.9 GiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
2         5271500         5279499   3.9 MiB     EF00  EFI system partition
3         6000640        30719999   11.8 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660  2021-08-19-11-03-38-00                                                    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660  2021-08-19-11-03-38-00               2cf4ba3a-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sda2      vfat     54C5-9C6C                            2cf4ba3a-02                                                   
└─sda3                                                    2cf4ba3a-03                                                   
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     68E1-6818                            a5242004-c6a9-4f41-920c-c19066c9b4d2                          EFI System Partition
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4     3b5fc5ee-e457-45ac-9714-04ca68b282dd e3fe6fb4-fa99-4b09-9d49-1cbdbbb2749d                          

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1         472.9M   7% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
nvme0n1p2            97G   7% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
sda1                   0 100% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1         rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
nvme0n1p2         rw,relatime
sda1              ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 3b5fc5ee-e457-45ac-9714-04ca68b282dd root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   3b5fc5ee-e457-45ac-9714-04ca68b282dd
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic   3b5fc5ee-e457-45ac-9714-04ca68b282dd
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=3b5fc5ee-e457-45ac-9714-04ca68b282dd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=68E1-6818  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.007831573 = 0.008409088    boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
   4.828136444 = 5.184172032    boot/vmlinuz                                   2
   4.828136444 = 5.184172032    boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic                 2
  50.703136444 = 54.442078208   boot/initrd.img                                3
  50.703136444 = 54.442078208   boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic              3
  50.703136444 = 54.442078208   boot/initrd.img.old                            3

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 Aug 12 09:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Aug 12 09:18 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Aug 12 09:18 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Aug 12 09:18 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Aug 12 09:18 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Aug 12 09:18 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Aug 12 09:18 41_custom


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[70841]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 6561: /bin/bash
Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.
=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[70841]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 6561: /bin/bash
Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.
```

Comment: If you ran boot-repair, you must have already had some problem you were trying to fix. Can you edit your question and include more details and context about the problems you are experiencing?

Comment: Boot-Repair would not corrupt partition tables. It primarily runs grub updates or grub installs and other standard commands to document system. As it suggests you may need parted rescue to try to recovery partitions. Do you have partition table backup or other documentation on what partitions you have? Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition Used parted rescue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362656 & https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#rescue

Comment: @Nmath I edited my questions and  included more info and pictures of the errors.

Comment: Doesn't make sense IMO to run boot-repair when all you're trying to fix is an installation that was not successful to begin with. First I would make sure that your motherboard BIOS is up-to-date. Refer to the documentation and support for your motherboard to do that. Then, *before installing* - you should format your hard drive as GPT. You can do this using "Disks" in the live session (Try Ubuntu when booting from installation media). Formatting will create a new partition table. Then you should be able to install Ubuntu. Let us know if this works for you

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled upon the same issues while installing Linux Mint - it seems grub can't write to NVRAM in the MacMini (no clue what that means, just repeating what I read), and thus it needs to do stuff a bit differently.

Then, you have two options:

- install rEFInd from MacOS and it will probably find your half-baked install and let you boot from it. A good guide is https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/refind/ (and there you can also find other things you might stumble upon)
- reinstall the OS by using a patched ISO like this one (from one of the t2linux wiki maintainers): https://github.com/AdityaGarg8/mbp-ubuntu/releases/tag/v20.04-5.15.11