# Grub rescue no such partition while updating to Win10

Tags: grub2, windows-7, windows-10

So, i wanted to update my Win7 partition to Win10. Besides Win7 I have installed a Ubuntu 14.04 and a Dualboot with Grub. 
So while updating to Win10 there was a restart and I ended up in the grub rescue console telling me:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue >
```

I can't boot to any of the installed operating systems.  When I type ls it tells me my partitions:

```
(hd0), (hd0, msdos5), (hd0, msdos3),(hd0, msdos2), (hd0, msdos1)
```

But the boot partition is (hd0, msdos6) which is not listed here.

What can I do the repair the Grub loader to finish Win10 installation AND rescue my Ubuntu?

Comment: Was Windows 7 UEFI or BIOS? Post this from live installer's terminal: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I think it was BIOS, have to get a Live CD first... Haven't thought about such issues

Comment: If BIOS, Windows may have forgotten to write your Linux partition back into partition table. It is still there, just needs to be in partition table. Old Windows bug going back many versions on any major update in Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080

Answer (score 0):

From your windows 10

Run a cmd as adminstrator and type:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Reboot

Comment: I can't boot to any of the installed operating systems, that includes also Win10.

Comment: Use a Windows install CD (Win7 works, too) to run this command. Or use a Linux Live CD and boot repair.

Comment: Ok, i will try it!

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work...

Comment: boot from cd win10 , when you see install Now hit ( shift + f10) to open cmd, type fixmbr \device\harddisk0 then type O and reboot

Comment: @GAD3R will this fix my dual boot or just enable to boot to Windows?

Comment: first time to boot from windows and next time to fix dual boot using bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Comment: I tried the command and all other variations of this, but still no grub at boot...