# Problems with Ubuntu and the Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair, windows-10

This is similar to a considerable amount of previous questions, but with an additional problem added on, so please skin to the last paragraph if you've seen this before.

I was running dual boot system, Linux 14.04 with Windows 7.  I decided to upgrade the Windows partition to Windows 10, and my Linux partition vanished and GRUB2 was malfunctioning.  As per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue), I fixed the GRUB2 problem, but the lost Linux partition was still unresolved.  I have since fixed that problem with Boot-Repair.

The problem I have now is that GRUB no longer showing a Windows partition.  Is there a method to fix this?  I need both operating systems (Windows for A/V stuff and Ubuntu for everything else).  Would I go with Boot-Repair again?  Thank you in advance for your replies.

Edit 1:
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e24Z.jpg) of the partition table.  The one labeled "unallocated" is where the Windows partition should be, and the other mass-partition WAS labeled unallocated" yesterday until fixed.

Edit 2: 
I apologize, I am presently unable to get Boot Info Script to work properly.  I will keep attempting until I can get it to work.

Edit 3:
I feel like an idiot.  I started a TestDisk to [look at the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QrsE.jpg) of the partitions and may have found the problem.  The two partitions share a single sector, which is screwing everything up.  I will attempt to fix it, having that information, and I will update again as soon as the attempt is complete.

Comment: Can you share the disk partitions either from Windows or Ubuntu? What are the specific error message and screen shots?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.