# Unable to boot without 'grub rescue> ' commands

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I have a system with dual boot  (debian 8/ windows 8)
After i formatted a drive from windows 8 i'm unable to boot even from usb, always it says 'Unknown Filesystem'.

Now, I can only boot the linux by using grub commands like

> set boot=(hd0,msdos1) 
> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub 
> insmod normal
>   
> normal

I've tried to format the drives after booting the debian 8, this way. But, still i can't get into the system without grub commands.

Now how can i boot from usb & install a new OS removing all the partitions ?

Comment: This is bordering on off topic, as it is not about Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you successfully boot your debian, correct the grub configuration and install new grub. I have never used debian but I believe it is similar to Ubuntu, so `sudo grub-install` would probably be the right command, after you change the grub config files. Maybe take a look here [Windows 10 upgrade led to grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655027#655027) where is says how you correct Ubuntu grub configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS is Debian, not Ubuntu. Should ask your question [here](http://forums.debian.net)

OR ask your question on IRC: irc.debian.org on channel #debian