# I was running windows 7 and ubuntu linux on the same laptop and I upgraded to windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I was running windows 7 and ubuntu linux on the same laptop and I upgraded to windows 10, everything seemed fine untill the laptop restarted and I got the black command screen saying grub rescue. All I wanted was to get my desktop files back. when I took my harddisk out from laptop and connected as an external drive to another, I can see what is in the hard disk but my desktop files do not exist. Anyone faced the same problem before and has been able to rescue their files please help :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 upgrade lead into grub rescue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue)

Answer (score 2):

When you install MS Windows 10, it overwrites the Grub contents in MBR to its own. All your Windows and Linux OS files are intact and good.

I tried this and it worked for my HP ENVY 15.

- Enter BIOS settings and go to BOOT options,
- choose Hard-Disk/SSD as the first boot option,
- as it shows a sub menu, press "enter" to see the sub-options,
- choose Grub as your first option,
- save and reboot.

Or you may need to do here is to repair you GRUB files.

- I used boot-repair and it worked very well for me.
- If you want to fresh install everything, Install Windows 10 first and then install Ubuntu.
- It is possible from that Grub-Rescue terminal itself to repair GRUB as suggested by other answers.

Comment: He may be able to get to terminal from grub repair and run sudo update-grub