# Windows 10 upgrade problem

Tags: windows-10

I have just upgraded my PC to Windows 10 after facing some problems like "grub rescue" but after upgrading ,every time I start PC  I have to write

```
prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
```

root=hd0,gpt6
Insmod normal
Normal

so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: sudo grub-install /dev/sdX

Comment: You need to reconfigure grub to use the correct partition at boot: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655027#655027

Answer (score 0):

Either Use A Live Ubuntu USB or boot into ubuntu and run command 
Open a terminal, and add the Boot Repair PPA

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

Install Boot Repair

> $ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Update the GRUB 2 configuration file

> $  sudo update-grub

Reinstall GRUB 2 to the drive's MBR or equivalent

Install to the drive, not to the partition. Example: sda, not sda1

> $ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX

Inspect the GRUB 2 configuration file. The default is /boot/grub/grub.cfg

for more information visit how to update [GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading)