# Windows Update on Dual Boot System

Tags: dual-boot, updates, windows, windows-10

Will installing a minor Windows update affect my Ubuntu system if I'm dual-booting? Not from one version of windows to another but just a small update. They are in separate partitions on my SSD so I'd suspect not but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Minor updates or the major Windows 7 to Windows 10? Minor updates may just overwrite boot loader if BIOS or reset Windows to first in boot order if UEFI. But if major update and BIOS, you may have partition table issues also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080

Comment: It's a minor bug fix update, not an entire os upgrade.

Comment: If just minor fixes, answer below then is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't... Worst case it might set back that it boots straight to Windows and doesn't show grub any more, but even that is relatively unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that Windows updates may not affect dual boot; reverse the order of dual boot (every time Windows updates, Ubuntu comes up 2nd) or; knock out the dual boot process.  How exactly, I don't know.  I fix it either by reinstalling Ubuntu (there is an option that repairs and saves your files) or; with a USB bootable stick and recovery mode.  In recovery mode, various options will clean & repair the grub entries.