# Unable to boot in to Ubuntu after Windows fall creator updates

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, bios

I have been booting in to Ubuntu 16.04 from the bios successfully that is until the windows 10 fall creator updates now prevents me doing so. My BIOS mode is UEFI and my Boot options are as follows:

```
Boot Option Menu
 OS boot Manager
 Ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 ubuntu <TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050>
 Boot From EFI File
```

Selecting the first Ubuntu in the BIOS shows the following error msg and opens Windows which is not what I want. Selecting the second ubuntu just opens Windows. Please note this error message was only viewable for a second at least and disappeared so I took a video and copied details down.

```
Malformed binary after Attribute Certificate Table
datasize: ? SumOfBytesHashed ? SecDir->Size:
hashsize: ? SecDir->VirtualAddress : 0x00000068
Failed to loadimage : Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned invalid Parameter
```

Windows works fine in normal startup.

I have read many posts/answers such as this one [https://askubuntu.com/questions/874181/windows-10-update-broke-my-mbr-grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJc6n.png) but am really not sure what I should do for my particular system.

This is my system partition after windows updates.
[system partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJc6n.png)

This my UEFI Boot order in BIOS system configuration.

```
UEFI Boot Order
OS boot Manager
Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive
USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk
USB CD/DVD ROM Drive
! Network Adapter
```

I tried re-ordering with `Secure Boot Disabled` but no luck.

I do understand I may have to either reinstall Grub and Ubuntu but some professional advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the Linux kernel image got corrupted by the action you mentioned. Simplest way to fix this is to reinstall the kernel by booting into a live Ubuntu (USB). Try replacing vmlinuz and initrd. Make sure you replace the right files by cross checking it with the grub configuration.

Comment: Ok. Before I go ahead to try this where will I find the vmlinuz and initrd files that you mention to try and replace.

Comment: ...and one more question for now - is it likely I will need to reinstall grub2 or should I do this without question?

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I reinstalled ubuntu/kubuntu distro with a live usb, reordered the list in the boot manager and now able to boot from the bios. I had hoped the new installation would detect the previous ubuntu but it did not. Clearly as is mentioned above - the Windows updates have corrupted the ubuntu partition. 
I have not yet tried replacing the vmlinuz and initrd - will try when I completely understand what I am doing.

Incidentally the windows updates don't all work AND windows can not display the correct time in the southern hemisphere BUT Linux can.

Comment: You can ask a separate question about Windows Time vs. Ubuntu Time.