# Is it safe to upgrade Windows version with Ubuntu installed alongside?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted with Windows 10 (UEFI system).

Is it safe for the Ubuntu bootloader to upgrade Windows (to the April creators update) ?

I have already both Windows and Ubuntu installed, so this is not a duplicate of how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows in UEFI. I am just asking whether upgrading Windows may corrupt the grub or the Ubuntu installation

Comment: Upgrades can always fail windows, Ubuntu, or otherwise so in that sense no upgrade is 'safe" back up first.

Comment: I have back up of data. I want to know if upgrading windows may break the Ubuntu installation

Comment: windows doesnt touch your other partitions, but the bootloader is overwritten in the update process, to save that, use a live usb stick, and open a terminal for reinstalling grub with the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` reboot and it will be as always

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 update broke my MBR / GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874181/windows-10-update-broke-my-mbr-grub) and [Unable to boot in to Ubuntu after Windows fall creator updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010127/unable-to-boot-in-to-ubuntu-after-windows-fall-creator-updates)