# PC boots into GRUB console after Windows update

Tags: boot, grub2

Yesterday I had to boot into Windows and when shutting down again Windows wanted to install updates (which is why I switched to Ubuntu in the first place).

Today I booted my PC and I get this screen:

[image]

Now I don't know what to do. Normally this is where the screen comes that lets me choose between Ubuntu 18.10 and the Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)  *ps: I know you didn't install windows, the windows-update caused the same issue as if it was just installed, and this contains fixes*

Comment: Another link that may be useful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/874181/windows-10-update-broke-my-mbr-grub  (windows 10 update broke my mbr-grub)

Comment: Thanks for that but sadly it doesn't work, it fails at the first command

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 10 Anniversary Update**, and the more recent **Windows 10 Creators Update**, have a really bad habit of wiping out Linux partitions on **MBR disks**. Microsoft has known about this bug for quite some time, but has chosen not to fix it. Sounds like you're a victim.

Recovery is possible, but it can be tricky.

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Open `Software & Updates` and make sure that all of your software repositories (except proposed) are enabled.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update           # update the software database
sudo apt-get install testdisk # install testdisk
man testdisk                  # read the manual
sudo testdisk                 # start testdisk
```

You can also get specific instructions here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

**Note**: after recovery, strongly consider changing your MBR formatted disk to GPT format, so future MS updates won't wipe it again.