# How to undo update-grub

Tags: boot

I just used the command "sudo update-grub" after having added nomodeset to the grub file. Now my laptop won't get past the empty violet linux booting screen. Any help on how to undo this?

I tried to use a terminal in safe mode, but I don't know how to edit the grub file with the terminal only (as gedit doesn't work on a terminal only).

Comment: If in grubmenu, you use e for edit and can edit boot stanza to remove or add nomodeset or other boot parameters. You can also go into grub terminal and manually boot but have to know details. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655027#655027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, sorry, apparently I didn't need to use a terminal. Pressing "e" while in grub selection will let me erase nomodeset :)

Comment: No need to apologize for finding your own solution.

Comment: So how do I close this question? or mark it as solved? does it do it automatically?

Comment: Click the checkmark next to the answer you like the most.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest terminal editor to use is probably going to be `nano` so a command like this could work:

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

You didn't specify exactly which of the grub configuration files you were editing. So it might be you have to type a different file name.

Comment: Yes, it was this grub file I edited, so this answer would surely work, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nano`.

```
nano filename
```

`Ctrl+O` to write to file and `Ctrl+X` to exit.