# Dual boot: Reinstalling Windows

Tags: dual-boot

The  10 year old's nephew's laptop was originally outfitted with XP and Ubuntu (dual-boot) upgraded.  Dual booted because I want him to use Linux (default boot OS) and select Windows only when he wants to use the laptop for robotics.

The goal is to replace XP  with Win7.  OS re-install (if it matters) will be done through bootable USB Win7 flash drive.  When responding, please indicate if you have replaced the OS on a dual boot partition.

This thread's goal is to understand the pitfalls and good process \ steps for a successful Win7 replacement and avoid damaging the Ubuntu partition.

## QUESTIONS

- Is there a checks \ steps that can prevent damaging the Ubuntu partition or GRUB?
- Is there a good reference (step by step) that outlines pitfalls and good practice?

Any lessons-learned / pitfalls to avoid are appreciated.   Thank you

Comment: Backup everything first. Windows will only install to a NTFS formatted partition with the boot flag. But all versions of Windows installs/upgrades often forget to write Linux logical partitions. Best to backup partitions table structure so you can easily recover it. `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt` Copy file to another device. While this was Windows 10 same issue with all major Windows installs. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a checks \ steps that can prevent damaging the Ubuntu partition?

- Don't touch the partitions Ubuntu is installed on. Don't even mount them during the Windows installation. Make damn sure you pick the correct partition(s) for Windows.
- Make a backup so if it does get destroyed you can re-install Ubuntu and re-install that backup.

> Is there a good reference (step by step) that outlines pitfalls and good practice?

- Not really. It is often a very specific situation you are in when you run into problems. So the pitfalls are many. Installing W7 might lead to a crash and we can not start to list the many problems you could end up with.
- BUT! If anything burn a boot repair DVD before you start. That will give you the option to restore grub and access to Ubuntu whatever the deal is with the Windows installation.

Some other advice: I myself have stopped using dual boots. Depending on your Windows and Ubuntu usage opt for installing the 2nd OS in a virtual machine (virtualBox or VM Ware). Then you have both systems ready without the need to reboot to use the other system. Using an SSD as a boot disk for this would be advisable though.

Comment: Boot repair DVD = sysrescuecd?  Or does it need to be created from the current instance of Ubuntu?  Hoping to avoid damaging grub. Dankje wel!

Comment: Any install or most repairs of Windows will reinstall Windows boot loader to MBR. Most of grub is in install, but you still have to reinstall grub2's boot loader. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System Often best to just add Boot-Repair to Ubuntu live installer of same version as you have installed.

Comment: Would you recommend a preferred post/resource to get started with setting up a virtual machine? This sounds like a valid option to explore. Personally, I would be interested in having Linux as host OS and Windows as guest.