# Linux partitions showing unallocated after recovering windows 7

Tags: 16.04, windows-7, testdisk, unallocated

This is little long but please bear with me. So I have 3 primary partitions and two logical partition under an extended partition. The first two primary partition sda1 & sda2 are root and home of my xubuntu. So I wanted to dual boot it with win7 and hence installed it in the third primary partition sda3. While updating grub through live cd I saw one logical partition showed up as unallocated. I used testdisk to recover the partition. I was able to recover the said partition but now my root & home show up as unallocated. I can't boot into Ubuntu as it is showing grub rescue error. I would like to recover my Linux partitions but at the least I hope to recover my home partition data. Can someone help me here?

Tldr: installed win 7 after Ubuntu;windows corrupted one partition and in fixing that partition my Linux partitions became unallocated. How to recover data from home?

Edit: thanks, was able to recover home partition via testdisk but when I try to set the partition as it was before windows I am unable to. Will update after more tryouts.

Comment: testdisk will recover your partitions but hard to say much else from what little you posted.

Comment: There's power outage here so can't post detailed information. Will update the post when power comes.

Comment: If you had multiple logical partitions, you need to recover each of them. Window has had & still has a bug(feature?) that forgets to write Linux partitions back to partition table when Windows updates partition table on major updates or installs. https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655080#655080 Be sure to backup current partition table, so if your choices in testdisk damage table you can easily restore to your current starting point.