# Can't find my bootloader (GRUB) after updating Windows

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader, grubrescue

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16,04.

I did an update on Windows and after the update I had to restart my computer. After restarting I have an error

```
Error : no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Windows can play such tricks in dual boot systems, when it is doing major updates/upgrades :-( Fortunately it is not too difficult to repair grub :-)

Comment: can you post your partition information?

Comment: Is it a grub issue, or really a missing partition. Windows on major updates may rewrite partition table and if BIOS/MBR forgets to write the Linux partition(s) back into partition table. Post this: `sudo parted -l`  If missing: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080

Answer (score 0):

Replace the HDD references with you particular partition information.

Ok, from grub type `ls (hd0,1)/`
you should see a file named vmlinuz or linux, and initrd.img

Type `linux (hd0,1)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1` or `linux (hd0,1)/linux root=/dev/sda1` depending on what you found with `ls (hd0,1)/`, then:

```
initrd (hd0,1)/initrd.img
boot
```

Use `gparted` to check your file system, if it reports an error, then you need to boot from a LiveCD or other media to fix it .... DO NOT attempt to repair a mounted partition.

The following three commands fix many grub boot problems. They run quick so just do all three instead of trying to find which one you need.

For  and EFI system:

```
sudo install-grub && sudo update-grub && sudo update-initramfs -u`
```

Reboot and see what you get.

Comment: all my partitions report unknown filesystem on the `ls` command ..