# Regarding dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

Our school provides students with pre-dual-boot-enabled laptops. Everything is going well switching between the two OSs until one day after I updated my Windows system and "error grub rescue" or something like that appeared and I couldn't boot any of my OSs at all.

Well, this is not the problem. I viewed some tutorials here and there and recovered my Windows system, but ever since then my laptop would boot straight to Windows and the GRUB loader disappeared.

I've been trying for about two days to recover my GRUB loader and log into my Ubuntu with methods I see over the webs but none of them seem to be working. Is there any way to tell if my laptop still have Ubuntu on it? How can I recover the GRUB loader?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Take look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655027

Comment: BIOS or UEFI system and installs? What brand/model? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

In Windows go to

Settings -> Update&Security -> Recovery -> Advanced Startup (Restart now)

Then Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> UEFI

You will reboot into the UEFI menu. Then check boot order. Windows puts itself first after every update. Make sure Ubuntu is on the top.

Complain at Microsoft regarding this behavior.