# GRUB with black screen?

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

After I rebooted, I got a black screen with GRUB, asking for commands.

How do I access my desktop so that I can use Boot-Repair to repair, reinstall and fix GRUB?

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists 
possible device or file completions.

grub> ls
(proc) (hd0) (hd) (hd0.gpt3) (hd0.gpt2) (hd0.gpt1) (hd1)
grub>
```

Comment: If you know which partition you have install. Change this to your partition. `configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` You can use `ls (hd0,1)/, etc to find partition also.

Comment: I do know that the code is something like (hd0,apt3)....   how do I apply your command ?

Comment: Full name is drive, partition. You can use gpt for gpt or msdos for MBR, but that is optional. If / is sda3, and grub sees hd0,3, sometimes drives change, my hd0 becomes hd1, if I have a flash drive plugged in as it becomes hd0. this only works if grub is otherwise ok. `configfile (hd0,3)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: No. Sorry. It did not worked.

Comment: You then can try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655027#655027

Answer (score 0):

I have a disk with Xubuntu  32x which will always boot up.

I have push the Left side Shift key & then push F12 to boot from the disk. After I have Erased & installed Xubuntu. I have done the same thing with disk with Ubuntu 64x, which is installing right now on this hard drive:

I have done the same thing before installed Windows 10 hard drive.

...  but ...  it does works. Maybe it’s the 32x version ?

It just works for me !!!