# Minimal BASH , grub error

Tags: grub2, login, live-usb, boot-repair

"Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."
grub>

I've been trying bootable live usb but stuck with this window. I don't know how to fix this issue and I'm unable to login to the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655027#655027 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting If you then can boot do grub install. or Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair