Recover /dev/sda to /dev/sda1?
I ran ntfsfix by a mistake as follows:
sudo ntfsfix -b /dev/sda

Instead of:
sudo ntfsfix -b /dev/sda1

Now my external hard drive does not show up anymore. If I run lsblk, I get:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1380
loop1         7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2         7:2    0 269.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4173
loop3         7:3    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1439
loop4         7:4    0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop5         7:5    0 269.8M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4698
loop6         7:6    0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop7         7:7    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop8         7:8    0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
loop9         7:9    0    14M  1 loop /snap/icon-theme-breeze/2
loop10        7:10   0  10.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1124
loop11        7:11   0   476K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
loop12        7:12   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 233.1G  0 part /media/lau/Local Disk
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   1.4G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 242.1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /

Any idea how I can restore or recover this external from /dev/sda to /dev/sda1? I have important data in it that I want to rescue.
Edit:
Using sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda:
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for lau: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Exact type match not found for type code 7200; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 7400; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 6500; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Disk /dev/sda: 3906963456 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model: My Passport 0748
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 1205348D-AA02-4799-95B8-4ACB0A5080CE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3906963422
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2204972979 sectors (1.0 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1       218129509      1920119918   811.6 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   2       729050177      1273024900   259.4 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   3       168653938               0   16.0 EiB    8300  Linux filesystem

Using fdisk -l /dev/sda:
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for lau: 
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Disk model: My Passport 0748
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x69205244

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        218129509 1920119918 1701990410 811.6G 72 unknown
/dev/sda2        729050177 1273024900  543974724 259.4G 74 unknown
/dev/sda3        168653938  168653938          0     0B 65 Novell Netware 386
/dev/sda4       2692939776 2692991410      51635  25.2M  0 Empty

Edit 2:
TestDisk 7.2, Data Recovery Utility, February 2024
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org


Disk /dev/sda - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - My Passport 0748

Please select the partition table type, press Enter when done.
 [Intel  ] Intel/PC partition
 [EFI GPT] EFI GPT partition map (Mac i386, some x86_64...)
 [Humax  ] Humax partition table
 [Mac    ] Apple partition map (legacy)
>[None   ] Non partitioned media
 [Sun    ] Sun Solaris partition
 [XBox   ] XBox partition
 [Return ] Return to disk selection



Hint: None partition table type has been detected.

Then I pressed 'enter' on my keyboard:
Disk /dev/sda - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - CHS 243197 255 63

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
>   P NTFS                     0   0  1 243197  57 60 3906963456

Enter again:
Disk /dev/sda - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - CHS 243197 255 63
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
   P NTFS                     0   0  1 243197  57 60 3906963456

Boot sector
Status: OK

Backup boot sector
Status: OK

Sectors are not identical.

A valid NTFS Boot sector must be present in order to access
any data; even if the partition is not bootable.

>[  Quit  ]  [  List  ]  [Org. BS ]  [Backup BS]  [Rebuild BS]  [  Dump  ]

Which option should I select to go forward? Backup BS?

Sorry that is not going to get fixed.

Does this show anything? sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda Or does testdisk show old partitions. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk Generally you should not be using NTFS unless using Windows as you cannot fix Windows NTFS issues from Linux. The ntfsfix primarily turns on the chkdsk flag, so next time you boot Windows it runs chkdsk.

@oldfred please see my edit above. What can I do next?

I find it kinda baffling that ntfsfix wouldn't check that the target is actually a partition. Leaving out the number at the end seems like a very easy mistake to make. Maybe I'm missing something. Anyways short of testdisk as oldfred suggested, you're probably left with recovering data using photorec. The good news is that your data is likely almost 100% intact. The bad news is that recovering with photorec is a hit and miss, and for sure you'll lose all files' metadata. I have a script laying somewhere that sorts files recovered by photorec by extension,I can post it if you need it.

@kos Please post it. Thanks

@Run Sure, I have it on one of my work machines. I'll grab the script later when I'm on that machine and post a bin, I'll leave a link to the bin once I've done it

@kos thanks so much!

I was hoping you had gpt not very old MBR(msdos). Gpt has a backup partition table at end of drive that may have allowed easy recovery. Try testdisk first & if you see files with deeper search immediately copy them. Some stopped & then lost files. I have used photorec, but without file name, only extension difficult to know what file is what. It recovers old files so multiple copies & some partial files. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step You need another drive to copy data into and it is very slow. Took overnight for a smaller drive for me on older system.

Here's the script; it's localized in Italian, also please don't tell people I wrote it (I wrote it years ago when I didn't even know what parameter expansion was :|) but it gets the job done, I still use it when I need to do data recovery. Use photorec to recover files somewhere (let's say /home/user/photorec), by doing that the target directory will be filled with recup_* dirs, containing the files. Run the script passing the recup_* dirs' parent as an argument (in this case /home/user/photorec) and it will sort the files in place

(it will also separate .jpg thumbnails from actual pictures, as often among the other garbage a lot of thumbnails will be recovered, most people care a lot about their photos so I built that automatic separation feature in). Good luck!

@kos how to use testdisk to do a deeper search copying my data? Any guide?

@kos please see my edit 2. thanks

I don't remember all the steps by heart, but basically in the screen you're at you should tell testdisk which partition table the drive originally used. If it's a 2TB drive, it could've been GPT. After that you should see a "Quick search" option and a finer-grained type of search available, you could start with "Quick search" and see if testdisk manages to find the original partition (NTFS, sized the way it was originally). If it does, you should follow the option to rewrite that partition table back to the disk.

@kos when I use photorec to recover files, it renames all my files, how can I keep the original file names?

@oldfred how to use testdisk to do a deeper search copying my data? Any guide?

You can't, the way photorec works is it scans the drive for known "file signatures" that will tell photorec which kind of file is currently scanning and then copy the file to the target dir; at no point it queries the filesystem on the partition[s] (that's kinda the point of photorec, filesystem / partition / partition table is borked => it will attempt to recover files anyways). That's also the reason why files are all thrown randomly in multiple directories, there's no information that photorec can (or attempts to) access to estabilish the original filesystem structure.

Photorec also has some tools to rename files. You can rename photos as date is inside photo info. https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files Use scripts to help sort and rename files:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec Testdisk: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue/655080#655080 & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery

This question is similar to: TestDisk - None partition table type has been detected. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
